# AlertDialog.Builder with a custom view: how to initialize the view?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm working on an `AlertDialog` for editing a list item. I can pass my editor layout with `Builder.setView`, and I can get the result from the positive button callback, but I don't see a way to initialize the view. E. g. there's an `EditText` that should be displaying a specific string, and so on. Is it doable?

I realize I could subclass `Dialog`, but then it seems I'd need more utility code to achieve the same result. Seems less clean.

Comment: "there's an EditText that should be displaying..."..Is this part of your view for `setView`?

Comment: @Shaishav: exactly.

Comment: Is the edit text defined in a layout file? If yes, share the name of the layout file?

Comment: If possible, show the code that you use to create the alert dialog

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply, retain a reference of the view by inflating it beforehand:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_label_editor, null);
dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);
```

Then, get a reference to your `EditText` as:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.label_field);
```

Comment: Eight years later... thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This very simple example will show you how to create a Alert dialog with editText (don't use xml layout, do it programmatically)

```
public void showDialogWithEditText(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        final EditText edittext = new EditText(this);
        alert.setTitle("Enter your name:");
        alert.setView(edittext);

        alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                String value = edittext.getText().toString();
                // use the value.

            }
        });

        alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                // cancel
            }
        });

        alert.show();
    }
```

Comment: I think you were answering the different question from mine, but I suddenly realized how to do what I need when reading your answer :) I should instantiate the view first (in this case - `EditText`), initialize it, and THEN pass it to the builder and call `create().show()`.

Comment: Yes, if you have multiple Views on the layout, you should define and inflate it from XML (Shaishav's answer). Then use setView(...) :) my answer just have a little bit useful for you :)

Comment: You can also do the same thing with 'Dialog', my short tip here: https://davidng94.wordpress.com/2015/12/16/android-custom-a-simple-dialog/